# Inserir nota de rodapé em legenda no Latex

Tags: latex

Como faço para inserir uma nota de rodapé na legenda de uma figura?

Com o código:

```
\begin{figure}[htb]
\centering
\begin{subfigure}[b]{.4\textwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{imagens/gui/atom}
  \caption{Visualização do conjunto}
  \label{fig:exmplo_1}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}[b]{.4\textwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{imagens/gui/plot-atom}
  \caption{Matriz scatter plots}
  \label{fig:exmplo_metricas_2}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Exemplo de matriz \textit{scatter plots} para conjunto de dados Atom\footnote{Fundamental Clustering Problem Suite} }
\label{fig:exemplo_scatter_plot}
\end{figure}
```

Retorna a mensagem de erro:

```
<to be read again> 
               \par 
l.382 ...de dados Atom\let \reserved@d =[\def \par
                                                   }}{37}{Exemplo de matriz ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente com `\footnotemark` e `\footnotetext` na mesma página:

```
\begin{figure}[!tbp]
        \centering
        \subfloat[Visualização do conjunto.]{\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{foo}\label{fig:exmplo_1}}
        \hfill
        \subfloat[Matriz scatter plots.]{\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{foo}\label{fig:exmplo_metricas_2}}
    %   \caption{Exemplo de matriz \textit{scatter plots} para conjunto de dados Atom .} \footnote{Fundamental Clustering Problem Suite}
    \caption[Exemplo de matriz \textit{scatter plots} para conjunto de dados Atom]{Exemplo de matriz \textit{scatter plots} para conjunto de dados Atom.\footnotemark}  
    \end{figure}
    \footnotetext{Fundamental Clustering Problem Suite} % na mesma página
     % antes da próxima footnote
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: value funcionou mas, quando a figura passa para outra página por causa do tamanho do texto, a nota de rodapé fica na página anterior. Sabe como resolver isso?

Comment: Tente com `\clearpage ` após o texto longo e antes de `\begin{figure}`, ou tente em outras posições até conseguir